# "sudo monit status" shows my process's status is Timeout, why?

Tags: linux, timeout, status, monit

in Linux, I used "sudo monit status" to check my process's status, and it shows Timeout. Does anybody know why? Thanks very much
[image]

Comment: What does the .conf script look like for your process? (timeout is usually that monit can't access the http port specified in the conf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely means your process that monit has been monitoring has crashed several times and monit is giving up on monitoring it.  Your conf file will declare this.

You can delete your state file and restart monit to get out of the timeout.